# pyodbc - slow insert into SQL server for large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, sql-insert, large-data

I have large text files that need parsing and cleaning. I am using jupyter notebook to do it. I have a sql server DB that I want to insert the data in after the data is prepared. I used `pyodbc` to insert the final dataframe into sql. `df` is my dataframe and I put my sql insert query in the field `sqlInsertQuery`

```
df_records = df.values.tolist()
cursor.executemany(sqlInsertQuery,df_records)
cursor.commit()
```

for a few rows it works fine, but when I want to insert the whole dataframe at once with the code above, with `executemany()` it lasts for hours and it keeps ruuning till I stop the kernel.
I exported one file/dataframe in an excel file and it is about 83 M, As my dataframe contains very large strings and lists.
Someone recommended using `fast_executemany` instead but seems it is faulty.
some others recommended other packages than pyodbc.
Some said better not to use jupyter and use pycharm or Ipython.
I did not get what is the best/fastet way to insert my data to my DB in my case. I am not a developer and I really appreciate if you help me on this.

Comment: Have you tried to use directly `df.to_sql`?

Comment: I used df.to_sql too. I tried the optimization options for both approaches but it did not change the issue-working super slow. The problem was with doing it remotely. I tried using both methods in non remote way and both worked fine and fast.